# Creating a Vertical Stack of HStacks with text and sliders swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Hi I have a Stack of Hstacks that consist of a Text and a slider. The slider width extends to the edge of the text in front of it but I want them all to have the same width and appear in a straight column.

[image]

Like this below.

[image]

This is how I am forming the stacks.

```
    VStack {
        ForEach(defensiveLayers.indices, id: \.self) { i in
            HStack {
                Text(defensiveLayers[i].name).font(.custom("Gill Sans", size: 12)).padding(.trailing).foregroundColor(.gray)
                MyNodeView(myNode: $defensiveLayers[i])
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the view where I am forming the sliders. Can someone pls help

```
struct MyNodeView : View {
    @Binding var myNode : Sliders
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.f", myNode.percent))%").font(.footnote)
            Slider(value: $myNode.percent, in: 0 ... 100)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you provide the first block of code correctly, it looks like you did not paste it correctly

Comment: Sorry I did not want to paste the whole class in here, so I just put the group of Vstack, I Just updated it.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure all the text is the same width, the simplest way is `.frame(width:)`.

```
struct Sliders {
    var name = "Name"
    var percent = CGFloat(100)
}
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var defensiveLayers = [
        Sliders(name: "Long name", percent: 80),
        Sliders(name: "Name", percent: 70),
        Sliders(name: "Ok name", percent: 65),
        Sliders(name: "Hi", percent: 15),
        Sliders(name: "Hello", percent: 45),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(defensiveLayers.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                HStack {
                    Text(defensiveLayers[i].name).font(.custom("Gill Sans", size: 12)).padding(.trailing).foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(width: 100) /// add frame here!
                    MyNodeView(myNode: $defensiveLayers[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MyNodeView : View {
    @Binding var myNode: Sliders
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.f", myNode.percent))%").font(.footnote)
            Slider(value: $myNode.percent, in: 0 ... 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Vertical stack sliders with text on left. Each slider's left position is the same no matter the text's length.]

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the required width for the longest `Text` and apply that particular width to all the leading `Text` views in all the `HStack`s unifying them in the width. I've created a helper method for finding the required width for any SwiftUI `View`.

Helper:

```
extension View {
    func viewSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
}

private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) { }
}
```

Usage:

```
@State private var textFrameWidth: CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(defensiveLayers.indices, id: \.self) { i in
            HStack {
                Text(defensiveLayers[i].name)
                    .font(.custom("Gill Sans", size: 12))
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .viewSize { size in
                        textFrameWidth = textFrameWidth < size.width ? size.width : textFrameWidth
                    }
                    .frame(width: textFrameWidth)
                MyNodeView(myNode: $defensiveLayers[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is preference() needed? Calling callback directly should also work: `GeometryReader { geometryProxy in onChange(geometryProxy.size); return Color.clear }`